# Is it possible to use FileSystemFetcher or S3Fetcher in tika-server in docker?

Tags: java, apache-tika, tika-server

The Tika provides some classes named: FileSystemFetcher, HttpFetcher, etc

Is it possible to use them for tika-server in docker?

It seems like this mechanism is in the development stage at this time cause there are no words about it in the documentation

For examples of dependencies and code, please

Comment: Y, those should both work assuming your mounted the volumes and opened the ports etc... See documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/tika-pipes Please let us know if you have any questions. Also please let us know how we can make this page more easily findable.